# Representing scatter plot data in a Venn diagramatic way?

Tags: r, matlab, graph, scatter-plot, variance

I have several scatter plots, representing different subsets of my data. I would like to find a way to visually represent the overlap/lack of overlap of these subsets of data. In R or in Matlab, what would be the best way to turn each set of data as an oval that takes into account the mean and variance of the data? I essentially want to turn three separate scatter plots into a Venn diagram, if that makes sense.

Comment: How about different colors for the dots coming from different subsets? Adding ellipses can of course be done, but different colors are dead easy.

Comment: This: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/whats-a-good-way-to-use-r-to-make-a-scatterplot-that-separates-the-data-by-trea might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `ellipse` function from the ellipse package to compute points on an ellipse, for each group of data you would give the ellipse function the means, standard deviations, and correlation, then pass the results to the `lines` function to add to the scatterplot.  This will work well if the groups are reasonably normal, but the ellipse will not fit well if there is strong skewness in a group.

Another option is to use the `chull` function to compute the complex hull that contains all the points in a group.  You can use this to plot a polygon that includes all the points (some will be touching the polygon).  If you want something more curvy than the polygon then use the `xspline` function to do the drawing rather than `lines` or `polygon`.  Here is some example code:

```
with(iris, plot( Petal.Width, Petal.Length, col=c('red','green','blue')[Species]))

tmp <- chull(iris[ iris$Species=='setosa', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length')])
xspline( iris[ iris$Species=='setosa', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length')][tmp,],
    border='red',open=FALSE, shape= -0.75)

tmp <- chull(iris[ iris$Species=='versicolor', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length')])
xspline( iris[ iris$Species=='versicolor', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length')][tmp,],
    border='green',open=FALSE, shape= -0.75)

tmp <- chull(iris[ iris$Species=='virginica', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length')])
xspline( iris[ iris$Species=='virginica', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length')][tmp,],
    border='blue',open=FALSE, shape= -0.75)



library(ellipse)

with(iris, plot( Petal.Width, Petal.Length, col=c('red','green','blue')[Species]))

polygon( ellipse( 
    var( iris[ iris$Species=='setosa', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length') ] ),
    centre=colMeans(iris[ iris$Species=='setosa', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length') ]),
    t=3),
    border='red')

polygon( ellipse( 
    var( iris[ iris$Species=='versicolor', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length') ] ),
    centre=colMeans(iris[ iris$Species=='versicolor', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length') ]),
    t=3),
    border='green')

polygon( ellipse( 
    var( iris[ iris$Species=='virginica', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length') ] ),
    centre=colMeans(iris[ iris$Species=='virginica', c('Petal.Width','Petal.Length') ]),
    t=3),
    border='blue')
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solutions given in the Q&A linked by @hrbrmstr, a litteral representation of it can be achieved using convex hulls:

```
library(scales) #Only for the transparency effect
data(iris)
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, type="n")
a <- split(iris, iris$Species) #Separate the dataset by ID (here species)
for(i in seq_along(a)){
    h <- chull(a[[i]]) #Compute convex hull for each group
    h <- c(h, h[1])
    polygon(a[[i]][h,], col=alpha(i,.5), border=NA) #Plot it
    }
points(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col=iris$Species, pch=19) #Add data points
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this with my dataset, I get the error "In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion" and the resulting convex hulls look botched. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1566200 without seeing your data, i can't really know what causes this issue. Out of the blue, I would assume it's a data type issue: check that everything that should be numeric is indeed numeric and not a character string or a factor.

Comment: Thanks, that's what it was. Had strings in it. This looks beautiful. Is there a way to add a legend for the colors with points()? Don't see it anywhere in help.

Comment: Look at `?legend`. Basically in this example you want to do something like `legend("bottomright", names(a), col=1:3, pch=19)`.